# I have two Different layouts for Mobile View and desktop view. How can I manage both Views in Single HTML using CSS? Is this possible with single view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a webpage where the design is different for Desktop and mobile view. Is it possible using only CSS and single layout of HTML?

Comment: Look up media queries.

Comment: Learn about css media queries - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries